# Connection refused when trying to download all books from project gutenberg (wget)

Tags: wget, project-gutenberg

I am trying to follow [Project Gutenberg's guide](https://www.gutenberg.org/policy/robot_access.html) to downloading all their english books in txt format but I am running into issues.
When I run the following command

```
wget -w 2 -m -H "http://www.gutenberg.org/robot/harvest?filetypes[]=txt&langs[]=en"
```

my system is unable to connect.
I keep getting these errors:

> Connecting to aleph.gutenberg.org
> (aleph.gutenberg.org)|65.50.255.20|:80... failed: Connection refused.

> Connecting to aleph.gutenberg.org
> (aleph.gutenberg.org)|2604:3200:0:3:1618:77ff:fe49:8a7|:80... failed:
> Network is unreachable.

I believe the error comes from the fact that the mirror "aleph.gutenberg.org" is down. How can I get the command to work (potentially by specifying another mirror to use such as "http://gutenberg.readingroo.ms/" for example).

Thanks.